# Convert different strings to snake_case in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, function

I know that we have a question similar to this, but not quite the same.

I'm trying to make my function work which takes in a string as an argument and converts it to [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). It works most of the time with all the fancy `!?<>=` characters, but there is one case that it can't convert and its [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

It fails when I'm passing strings like `snakeCase`. It returns `snakecase` instead of `snake_case`.

I tried to implement it, but I ended up just messing it up even more...

How can I do it?

My code:

```
const snakeCase = string => {
    string = string.replace(/\W+/g, " ").toLowerCase().split(' ').join('_');

    if (string.charAt(string.length - 1) === '_') {
        return string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
    }

    return string;
}
```

Comment: `but there is one case that it can't` What input does it fail for, and what were you expecting instead?

Comment: when I'm passing strings like `snakeCase` it returns `snakecase` instead of `snake_case` - so basically it fails on every camelCase string

Comment: Have a look at my answer below @dragi - it should cover all your use-cases 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to be able to detect the points at which an uppercase letter is in the string following another letter (that is, not following a space). You can do this with a regular expression, *before* you call `toLowerCase` on the input string:

```
\B(?=[A-Z])
```

In other words, a non-word boundary, followed by an upper case character. Split on either the above, or on a literal space, *then* `.map` the resulting array to lower case, and then you can join by underscores:

```js
const snakeCase = string => {
    return string.replace(/\W+/g, " ")
      .split(/ |\B(?=[A-Z])/)
      .map(word => word.toLowerCase())
      .join('_');
};

console.log(snakeCase('snakeCase'));
```

Comment: Can this be expanded to avoid adding a `_` when consecutive uppercase letters are encountered? One problem is when you call `snakeCase('CustomerID')` the result is `customer_i_d`, when simply `customer_id` is prefered.

Comment: I got it to work with this, but it seems excessive. `const s7 = string => {
    return string.replace(/\W+/g, " ")
      .split(/ |\B(?=[A-Z]{2,})/).map(word => word[0] + word.substr(1,).toLowerCase()).join('').split(/ |\B(?=[A-Z])/).map(word => word.toLowerCase()).join('_')
};`

Comment: @h0r53 - I just moved the `.toLowerCase()` to apply to the whole string, before the split: `string.toLowerCase().split(...)`

Comment: @mheavers that breaks it working with `snakeCase` which was the whole point to begin with. Or am I missing something?
 ```string.replace(/\W+/g, " ")
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(/ |\B(?=[A-Z])/)
      .map(word => word.toLowerCase())
      .join('_');```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for cases where the string is in uppercase, such as HELLO_WORLD

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the string is `Hello World?` and you want the returned value as `hello_world?` (with the character, then follow the below code)

```
const snakeCase = (string) => {
  return string.replace(/\d+/g, ' ')
    .split(/ |\B(?=[A-Z])/)
    .map((word) => word.toLowerCase())
    .join('_');
};
```

Example

```
snakeCase('Hello World?')
// "hello_world?"

snakeCase('Hello & World')
// "hello_&_world"
```

Comment: A very nice solution. I went even that far to replace multiple repetitive occurrences of underscore to a single one only: `str.replace(/\W+/g, " ").split(/ |\B(?=[A-Z])/).map((word) => word.toLowerCase()).join("_").replace(/(_)(?=\1+)/gm, "");` The `replace(/(_)(?=\1+)/gm, "")` replaces "____" into a single "_". E.g. "Hello_World" would resolve in "hello_world" instead of "hello__world"

Answer (score 5):

Let's try that again Stan... this **should** do snake_case while realising that `CamelCASECapitals` = `camel_case_capitals`. It's basically the accepted answer with a pre-filter.

```
let splitCaps = string => string
    .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z]+)/g, (m, s1, s2) => s1 + ' ' + s2)
    .replace(/([A-Z])([A-Z]+)([^a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/, (m, s1, s2, s3) => s1 + s2.toLowerCase() + s3)
    .replace(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/g, 
        (m, s1, s2) => s1.toLowerCase() + ' ' + s2);
let snakeCase = string =>
    splitCaps(string)
        .replace(/\W+/g, " ")
        .split(/ |\B(?=[A-Z])/)
        .map(word => word.toLowerCase())
        .join('_');
```

```js
> a = ['CamelCASERules', 'IndexID', 'CamelCASE', 'aID', 
       'theIDForUSGovAndDOD', 'TheID_', '_IDOne']

> _.map(a, snakeCase)

['camel_case_rules', 'index_id', 'camel_case', 'a_id', 'the_id_for_us_gov_and_dod', 
 'the_id_', '_id_one']

// And for the curious, here's the output from the pre-filter:

> _.map(a, splitCaps)

['Camel case Rules', 'Index Id', 'Camel Case', 'a Id', 'the id For us Gov And Dod', 
 'The Id_', '_id One']
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I’m on my phone so can’t check, but I’d happily take your word for it. I’ve edited my answer to link to yours 

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this answer isn’t foolproof. The fool, being me ;-) Please check out a better one by Orwellophile here: *[Convert different strings to snake_case in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963900/convert-different-strings-to-snake-case-in-javascript/69878219#69878219)*

——

I think this one should cover all the bases

It was inspired by @h0r53's answer to the accepted answer. However, it evolved into a more complete function, as it will convert *any* string, `camelCase`, `kebab-case` or otherwise into `snake_case` the way you'd expect it, containing only `a-z` and `0-9` characters, usable for function and variable names:

```
convert_to_snake_case(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + string.slice(1) // Lowercase the first character
      .replace(/\W+/g, " ") // Remove all excess white space and replace & , . etc.
      .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])([a-z])/g, "$1 $2$3") // Put a space at the position of a camelCase -> camel Case
      .split(/\B(?=[A-Z]{2,})/) // Now split the multi-uppercases customerID -> customer,ID
      .join(' ') // And join back with spaces.
      .split(' ') // Split all the spaces again, this time we're fully converted
      .join('_') // And finally snake_case things up
      .toLowerCase() // With a nice lower case
  }
```

Conversion examples:

```
'snakeCase'                  => 'snake_case'
'CustomerID'                 => 'customer_id'
'GPS'                        => 'gps'
'IP-address'                 => 'ip_address'
'Another & Another, one too' => 'another_another_one_too'
'random ----- Thing123'      => 'random_thing123'
'kebab-case-example'         => 'kebab_case_example'
```

Comment: fails on `aID`, `TheONE`, and many others.  Sorry :)  You can pull apart my answers for faults if it helps any :p

Comment: This doesn't work. Try `'HELLO_WORLD'`

Comment: Hence my edit at the very top. Try reading the whole text next time. This one is better / covers more use-cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963900/convert-different-strings-to-snake-case-in-javascript/69878219#69878219

Answer (score 1):

There is method in [Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash) named snakeCase(). You can consider that as well.

*[_.snakeCase([string=''])](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#snakeCase)*

Answer (score 1):

@Orwellophile's answer had a few issues that made it unusable for me.

Here is my solution:

```
const snakeCase = (string, trim = false, remove_specials = false, underscored_numbers = false) => 
string
    .replace(remove_specials ? /[^A-Za-z0-9_ ]/gm : '', '')
    .replace(/([_ ]+)/gm, '_')
    .replace(trim ? /(^_|_$)/gm : '', '')
    .replace(underscored_numbers ? /([^A-Z0-9_])([^a-z_])/gm : /([^A-Z0-9_])([^a-z0-9_])/gm, (m,preUpper,upper)=> `${preUpper}_${upper}`)
    .replace(underscored_numbers ? /([^0-9_][0-9]|[0-9][^0-9_])/gm : '', (m,i)=> i?i.split('').join('_'):'')
    .replace(/([A-Z])([A-Z])([^A-Z0-9_])/gm, (m,previousUpper,upper,lower)=> `${previousUpper}_${upper}${lower}`)
    .toLowerCase();
```

It can be provided settings, such as trimming start and end underscores, filtering out non alphanumeric characters, and whether numbers should be treated as separate words or letters.

From what I tested, every scenario seemed to have been handled as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Orwellophile's answer does not work for uppercase words delimited by a space:
E.g: 'TEST CASE' => t_e_s_t_case

The following solution does not break consecutive upper case characters and is a little shorter:

```
const snakeCase = str =>
  str &&
  str
    .match(/[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]*|\b)|[A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]*|[A-Z]|[0-9]+/g)
    .map(x => x.toLowerCase())
    .join('_');
```

However, trailing underscores after uppercase words (examples from Orwellophile as well), do not work properly.
E.g: 'TheID_' => the_i_d

Taken from https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/fundamental/javascript-fundamental-exercise-120.php.